# Как подключить файл json в виде массива в php?

Tags: php, json, файлы

Есть json в отдельном файле, как подключить его и получить из него массив?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

file_get_content выдаёт такую ошибку:
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in W:\domains\test\credit.php on line 44

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in W:\domains\test\credit.php on line 44

Warning: file_get_contents(https://test/assets/offers-ids.json): Failed to open stream: operation failed in W:\domains\test\credit.php on line 44
bool(false)

Код PHP:

```js
$file = file_get_contents($url_ids, 1);
var_dump($file);
```

Comment: `$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$options = [
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ],
];  
$fileContents = file_get_contents($url_ids, false, stream_context_create($options));
$array = json_decode($fileContents, 1);
```

***ВАЖНО:*** это не безопасно, поэтому лучше установить сертификат, а не отключать проверку ssl